# Searching for a record where an array contains an item

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm currently trying to find out how to search for a mongoDB document that contains an array. I want to find any records that have an array containing value X. Below is an example of my document structure.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("577d5c3c2c7e949307270d43"),
"name" : "Cruise Data",
"author" : "test",
"source" : "",
"headings" : [ 
    "﻿\"Arrival Date\"", 
    "Vessel", 
    "Cruise Call", 
    "Hash Items", 
    "Row Hash"
],
"data" : {
    "1" : [ 
        "05 Jan 2016", 
        "Black Watch (Fred Olsen)", 
        "Turnaround", 
        "b5740452f7d83a243d84fc3d8f72b312"
    ],
    "2" : [ 
        "26 Apr 2016", 
        "Boudicca (Fred Olsen)", 
        "Transit", 
        "0bf1b79a58b4bb943763f3745543497b"
    ],
},
"updated_at" : ISODate("2016-07-06T19:30:04.799Z"),
"created_at" : ISODate("2016-07-06T19:30:04.799Z")
```

}

The value I'm searching for is the MD5 hash in the data object. (ex: 0bf1b79a58b4bb943763f3745543497b). I've tried a couple of variations of `db.getCollection('datasets').find({data: {})` but had no luck. Is someone able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to model your field 'data' in such a format that it has known keys. For example:

```
"data": [
    {
        id: '1',
        date: "05 Jan 2016",
        name: "Black Watch (Fred Olsen)",
        type: "Turnaround",
        md5: "b5740452f7d83a243d84fc3d8f72b312"
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        date: "26 Apr 2016",
        name: "Boudicca (Fred Olsen)",
        type: "Transit",
        md5: "0bf1b79a58b4bb943763f3745543497b"
    }
]
```

And then you can find it easily by following query:
`db.datasets.find({'data.md5':'0bf1b79a58b4bb943763f3745543497b'})`

If it is impossible to change the data model, then you can use `$where` and write your custom javascript logic to find the element(s). See documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/

Here is the query to find documents from `datasets` collection which have 'Turnaround' on 2nd index of any sub-subdocument of 'data' sub-document:

```
 db.datasets.find({ $where: function () { var searchItem = 'Turnaround';  var dataObj = this.data; for (var key in dataObj) { var valueList = dataObj[key]; if (valueList.indexOf(searchItem) != -1) { return true; } } return false; } })
```

Please note that `$where` does not utilize indexes, so use it at your own risk :P

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response Manish. Is there no other way to do this without adding named keys?

I'm using data that I don't know the structure of (importing CSVs as individual documents) so keying them may be difficult. I'll also look in to imposing column headers in there though, just in cause.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still going to look in to changing the dataset programatically though, losing indexes is probably too big a loss

Comment: In the meantime should the following be working? Doesn't seem to: `db.getCollection('datasets').find(function() { return this.data[2] == 'Turnaround' })`

Comment: You need a query to find documents from `datasets` collection which have ''Turnaround" on 2nd index of any sub-subdocument of 'data' sub-document. Am I right?